# font size smaller than xx-small of matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

For plotting using matplotlib, how can I make `fontsize` smaller than `xx-small` of matplotlib?
Thank you very much.

Ref: http://matplotlib.org/users/text_props.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the documentation states, you can also set the `fontsize` in points. So if you set it to 4pt it is smaller than `'xx-small'`.

Example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sizes = [10,8,6,4,'xx-small']

for n,s in enumerate(sizes):
    plt.text(0,n,str(s), fontsize=s)

plt.xlim([-0.5, 0.5])
plt.ylim([-1, len(sizes)])
plt.show()
```

Result:
 [image]

Comment: But then the fontsize will not be relative but absolute ...